# Lightweight socket library that is compatible with Mono 2.6.3?

Tags: http, sockets, mono

I am looking for a lightweight socket library that is compatible with Mono 2.6.3. Specifically, we need to make synchronous (blocking) HTTP requests inside our Mono-based code, and can't use the built-in .NET sockets or Http classes for various reasons.

We had some luck with Indy Sockets before, but since Mono upgraded to the .NET 3.5 framework we've had no luck finding or building a version of Indy that works in that environment. Indy is a strange beast, with its roots in Delphi and nearly impenetrable documentation. Do any of you know of something friendlier that could do the job? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There a .NET binding of [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). You can find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-net/).
cUrl is at a higher level of abstraction than sockets, but in your case should do the job.

I've never used this specific binding and the project seems rather old.

The cUrl website mentions also a [Mono binding](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/mono/) but the link seems to go nowhere.